# PHP replace string with word from another string

Tags: php, regex

There are two variables:

```
$string1 = "Source for replace";
$string2 = "String {Word2} replace";
```

I need to replace **{Word 2}** from the second variable with the corresponding word from the first constant (the second word will be - *for*). If **{Word 2}** the replaced word should be with a capital letter, and if **{word}** - with a small one.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` with some logic.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Then give a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bored:

```
$words = explode(' ', $string1);

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\{(word(\d+))\}/i',
    function($m) use($words) {
        if($m[2] > count($words)) { return $m[0]; }     
        if($m[1][0] == strtoupper($m[1][0])) { return ucfirst($words[$m[2]-1]); }
        return lcfirst($words[$m[2]-1]);
    }, $string2);
```

- Check to see if the digit is greater than the count of words
- Check for capitalization `Word`/`word`
- Return the word from the proper index of the words array

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to do what you described.

```
$string1 = "Source for replace";
$string2 = "String {Word2} replace";

//This will separate the string based on spaces
$arr1 = explode(' ', $string1);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $string2);

//Check the arrays are the same size
if( sizeof( $arr1 ) != sizeof( $arr2 ) ){
    echo "Your arrays are not the same size. This will cause error. Stop.";
    die();
}

//Find the occurence of {word2} in array 2
if( in_array('{word2}', $arr2) !== false ){
    $arr2key = array_search('{word2}', $arr2);
} else {
    $arr2key = array_search('{Word2}', $arr2);
}

//Replace the key in array 2 with the corresponding key from array 1
$arr2[$arr2key] = $arr1[$arr2key];

//Join array 2 back together again with spaces.
$string2 = implode(' ', $arr2);

echo $string2;
```

This code will replace {word2} or {Word2} from the second string, no matter where, with the corresponding word from the first sentence. If the two sentences are NOT the same length, there will be an error and the program will stop.

In future, please be more specific when you ask your question, and make sure you include any code that you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

I use preg_match to find the "{word}" and what digit it has.
Then I explode the first string and use str_replace and replace the "{word}" with the index of the exploded string minus one.
I assume you want to count line humans and not like arrays, if I'm wrong just remove -1.

```
$string1 = "Source for replace";
$string2 = "String {Word2} replace";

Preg_match("/(\{word(\d+)\})/i", $string2, $matches);

$arr =explode(" ", $string1);

$str = str_replace($matches[1], $arr[$matches[2]-1], $string2);
Echo $str; // String for replace
```

https://3v4l.org/Hfotp

This can cause an notice if word digit is higher than the count of words in $string1 but you can solve that with:

```
$arr =explode(" ", $string1);
If($matches[2] <= count($arr)){
    $str = str_replace($matches[1], $arr[$matches[2]-1], $string2);
    Echo $str;
}Else{
    Echo "there is no index " . $matches[2] . " in $string1";
}
```

If that is needed